# Read Fillable PDF form fields in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, pdf, adobe, fdf, aspose.pdf

I have a fillable PDF form created using Adobe Acrobat DC and I want to submit this form to a URL: http://localhost:49168/WebForm1.aspx.

I am using Aspose.Pdf library to read the PDF file on my code but whenever I am trying to read the file it throws an exception: "Incorrect file format". Can anybody help/guide me how to read the fields from this form.[image: Settings on Adobe DC]

Below is code I am trying to use:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string pdftype = Request.ContentType;
        int pdfocument = Request.ContentLength;
        try
        {
            byte[] pdf = new byte[pdfocument];
            Stream stream = new MemoryStream(pdf);
            Aspose.Pdf.Facades.Form form = new Aspose.Pdf.Facades.Form(stream);

         //   HttpContext.Request.InputStream.Read(pdf, 0, pdfocument);
            Document doc = new Document(stream);


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        } 

    }
```

Comment: Would you please mind sharing the the input PDF file, so that we can test the scenario and share our findings. The issue appears to be document specific.

My name is Nayyer and I am developer evangelist at Aspose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue with using HTML export format instead of FDF format and read the values using Form collection.